# How to get started with input methods?

Tags: x11, input-method

A couple of years back I managed to set it up somehow that I could write ae to get ä, AE to get Ä, oe to get ö etc. Without pressing the compose key.

Similar to swedish-postfix input method in Emacs, but it worked for all windows, browsers, terminals etc and I could toggle it.

But I have no idea how I did this. On Debian, how do I get started with installing input methods like this and activating/deactivating them, actually using them?

Outside of Emacs, which has this built in and doesn't need an external input method for it, I typically use dwm, rxvt, Firefox and Inkscape.

Comment: You were probably using some kind of `XIM` (X11 input method).  This is a wild guess, since I do not use it, but `fcitx-m17n` may be the [`fcitx`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx) part that has swedish characters.  There are other XIM's than `fcitx`, but most of them are for japanese/chinese (`fcitx` is mostly for japanese/chinese, but has a bigger number of supported languages.).

Comment: Yeah, some sorta XIM or UIM or similar but I don't remember how I actually set it up and activated/deactivated it, or which one I was using. :/ Thanks.